# How setting IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP in a C#-Application

Tags: c#, windows

I want to set IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP in a C#-Console-Application which will be run from a network-share.

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313(v=vs.85).aspx

How can I do this?

Comment: @Arnaud - you should explain what you don't like in the given answer

Comment: @SimonMourier In fact, I really much liked it and only wanted to give it the bounty. If only this answer existed in 2016 it would have saved me quite some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can set the Flags in the PE-Header with

```
editbin /swaprun:CD /swaprun:NET <exe-file>
```